# having issues getting a circle to change colors using hover in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js, hover, fill

I have added some circles on a map and would like the circle to change from black to orange when hovering over it.  I've tried two different approaches:

1. css:
   circle: hover {
   fill: orange
   }
2. with a mouseover event.  Part of the mouseover works (I can change the radius of the circle for example), but setting the fill to a different color is not working.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

in case you haven't found an solution, here's my suggestion
first add a class to the circle , then add mouseover and mouseout

```
.attr("class","circleClass")
.on("mouseover",mouseover)
.on("mouseout",mouseout)
```

after you can use mouseover and mouseout to change color

```
function mouseover(event){
    $(".circleClass").css({"fill":"blue"})
}
function mouseout(event){
    $(".circleClass").css({"fill":"red"})
}
```